# Unable to add Controller or View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2017

I having problem in adding controller to the Project using Visual Studio 2017. I added the option by of ADD CONTROLLER  using tools/Customize/commands.
But even after that I am unable to add it. I can just make copy of a controller and edit. 
But I need solution where I can add the controller directly and generate the View.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/mvc-controller) if you are very new to this.
Generally in an MVC project in Visual Studio to add a controller just right click on **Controllers** folder, then **Add** then **Controller...**

Comment: You... sort of can. I mean you used to be able to. But when I do it now, I can only add Web API controllers, and this is an MVC app that I'm working on. Seems like a bug.